# Python - Not reading from file?

Tags: python, file-io, generator

I'm playing with the generator for processing infinite data, located [here](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/), which is a pretty simple thing for returning the tail from a file:

(Source code from [here](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/follow.py))

```
# follow.py
#
# Follow a file like tail -f.

import time
def follow(thefile):
    thefile.seek(0,2)
    while True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line

# Example use
# Note : This example requires the use of an apache log simulator.
# 
# Go to the directory run/foo and run the program 'logsim.py' from
# that directory.   Run this program as a background process and
# leave it running in a separate window.  We'll write program
# that read the output file being generated
# 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logfile = open("run/foo/access-log","r")
    loglines = follow(logfile)
    for line in loglines:
        print line,
```

My issue is that using a test file, '/var/log/test.log' when I write to it, it doesn't print anything to the console I have my generator working on.

I can print the file from other terminals and see that the new lines are added, but the python code doesn't seem to read the new data?

I thought that maybe it was an issue reading from /var/log/ so I created another file in /Users/Me/Python/ and it still won't read the data.

I feel like I'm missing something really simple :(

Edit:

(I'm on OSX, Python 2.7.5 btw) I tried it out line by line, like so:

```
FID = open(fileName, 'r')
FID.seek(0,2)
FID.tell() # For example says 125
FID.readlines() # returns []
# Now I edit the log file, add in a couple of new lines (in TextMate if that helps)
FID.readlines() # returns []
FID.seek(0,2)
FID.tell() # returns 125
os.stat(fileName) # says size is 142
```

Is my file descriptor not reading the updated file or something?

Comment: Can you post what you do have

Comment: I have tried your code on my machine, it works.... What's your environment?

Comment: Indeed, works for me too.

Comment: I'm on OSX, and what I have is exactly the same as above except it currently points to a file in my /dev/Python/ folder. I've verified I can open it and output it to the screen, but it won't grab new things as they're saved to the file

Comment: are you sure that you use the same file? Your code reads `run/foo/access-log`, but the text references `/var/log/test.log`.

Comment: In the last snipped of code, fileName = '/User/Me/dev/Python/test.log'
I verify I can read the file (I can print out the contents to the interpreter), I check the size of the file, then I write new stuff to the file, recheck the size to see it has grown, but `FID.read()` and `FID.readlines()` don't return the new lines. FID.seek(0, 2) takes me to the original size, but not to the newer size. (Size after editing)

Comment: Do the instructions in the code work in your environment i.e., 1. run `logsim.py` in a background 2. then run `follow.py` and see that the file generated by `logsim.py` grows.

Comment: Note: following a file descriptor differs from following a file by name e.g., if you are editing the file by hand; you editor might use `rename` to save a temporary file used for editing instead of appending to the original file. Compare output of `tail -f` and `tail -F` to see the difference (the later might use `inotify` or similar capabilities for your OS to monitor file's directory or it may just reopen the file by name if the file hasn't changed for several iterations).

Comment: I wrote a snippet of code to check if the file size has changed, and if it has to open the file, go to the previous size, read till the end, and close the file. It seems to work but feels very unpythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem on OSX Yosemite with Brew's Python 2.7.8

Fixed it by adding the following just before trying to read freshly added data:
FID.seek(0, os.SEEK_CUR)

This does not really change the filepointer, but somehow invalidates some cached state and sees new data.

Let me know if this works for you as well.